# how to design an app that's compatible for older android versions, but uses high API levels when possible?

Tags: android

Given an android app that many of its features are based on APIs that is from the latest android version (highest API level), like andvanced animations and notifications.

Now, this app needs to be comptatible with older android versions (lower API levels).

What is the best practice to do that?

Possible practices can (maybe) be:

- Refactoring the entire app while compromising on more basic functionality. (then what? publish both versions?)
- Somehow importing the high APIs we are using. (is it even possible?)
- including both high and low API implementations and getting the app to figure out in run-time which implementation to use.

Comment: Best practice is to decide what level you wish to support up front, and to write it using only those features from the beginning (possibly with an advanced feature gated by runtime version checks).  Deciding you suddenly need to support lower versions after writing it is just about the worst way of doing things.

Comment: I agree. however, what if I want to use high api level when it's possible? Or if I don't want to compromise on basic functionality?

Comment: You can runtime check the version and gate functionality on that.  Depending on if the functionality needs hardware support or not you may be able to replicate some functionality yourself for lower API levels, it all depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms